# Exception in Application start method - Javafx control class

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have already read all the old question, but I don´t understand what´s happened.
The Problem come only when I try to connect the file layout.fxml with the control Class.
I have try 1.000 path but it doesn´t work...
I need your help, and sorry for the stupid question :(

error:

```
> Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/claudio/Documents/workspace/KlickiBunti/Layout.fxml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2440)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at control.Main_Controller.start(Main_Controller.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application control.Main_Controller
```

Layout.fxml Class:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="354.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="Controller.java">
   <children>
      <MenuBar AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <TextArea layoutX="14.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="hey" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main Class:

```
package control;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
public class Main_Controller extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(new File("Layout.fxml").toURI().toURL())));
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

Control Class:

```
package control;

public class Controller {

    Controller (){

        System.out.println("Try");

    }


}
```

The 3 Classes are in the same path.

Maybe is for you a stupid question, but I try since 6 hours to resolve my Problem -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/claudio/Documents/workspace/KlickiBunti/Layout.fxml (No such file or directory).
```

You should load the FXML file as a resource anyway: if (when) you bundle the application as a jar file, the FXML will not be an independent file on the file system anyway (and even if you don't, `new File()` resolves relative to the working directory, over which you have no control).

If the FXML file is in the same package as the class from which it is being loaded, you should do

```
stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Layout.fxml"))));
```

If it is in the same package as the controller class `Controller`, you could also do

```
stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(Controller.class.getResource("Layout.fxml"))));
```

Additionally, the `fx:controller` attribute is expecting the *fully qualified classname* of the controller (i.e. `package.ClassName`), not the Java source file (which is not even available at runtime, for obvious reasons).

Comment: i´ve tried both and more things.. and all are working, but when I give the path for the Controller Class in Scene Builder I receive the same error and it doesn't´ work

Comment: @antoio You can't possibly get the same error if you make the changes I suggested. `getClass().getResource(..)` cannot possibly generate a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: now is: 
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/claudio/Documents/workspace/KlickiBunti/bin/control/Layout.fxml:8
and:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Controller

Comment: @antoio So why did you say it was the "same error", when it is clearly a different error? This means that the original problem (not being able to load the FXML file) is fixed, and now you can see errors that come from the FXML file itself. I edited your question to make the FXML visible (and fixed the bad formatting): I have updated the answer with the fix for the additional error.

Comment: i´m very sorry for the formatting and the bad answer.
Now I´ve wrote: control.Controll  (package.ClassName) and this is the Error:

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/claudio/Documents/workspace/KlickiBunti/bin/control/Layout.fxml:8
And:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil can not access a member of class control.Controller with modifiers ""

Comment: thank you very much. All the errors are fixed.
you are right, I´m in the first semester and I programming only since 6 Months. I´ve to learn first how to use StackOverflow and then maybe I´ve to learn English too.
I apologize. I wish you a good night.